# Savon/Ruby - Unable to add ':info' to specific XML tag

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, savon

I am currently trying to run a Soap Call in Ruby. Using Savon client, I am not getting the response I want. This is the XML I want to create:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:sch="http://test.com/requests/test-manager/schema">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
         <sch:createTestDateRequest>
            <sch:testMethod>DD</sch:testMethod>
             <sch:testPeriodNumber>999</sch:testPeriodNumber>
             <sch:testDateTime>2017-12-14 00:00:00</sch:testDateTime>
             <sch:name>Automated test</sch:name>
           </sch:createTestDateRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I've written the following code to create that Soap Call:

```
   require 'savon'
   $soap_client_testmgr = Savon.client(
        wsdl: 'http://test.com/test-manager-ws/TestManagerSoapService?wsdl',
        namespace: 'http://test.com/requests/test-manager/schema',
        env_namespace: :soapenv,
        namespace_identifier: :sch,
        pretty_print_xml: true,
        log: true,
        log_level: :debug)

    $soap_client_testmgr.call(:create_test_date, message: {
            :testMethod => 'DD',
            :testPeriodNumber => $test_period,
            :testDateTime => (Date.today+7).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' 00:00:00',
            :name => 'Automated test'})
```

But the XML that is generated is the following, missing the :sch before every individual name tag. This should be taken from the WSDL, correct? I've looked into namespace identifiers, but I have yet to find a fitting solution.

```
    <soapenv:Body>
        <sch:createTestDateRequest>
          <testMethod>DD</testMethod>
          <testPeriodNumber>999</testPeriodNumber>
          <testDateTime>2017-12-14 00:00:00</testDateTime>
          <name>Automated test</name>
        </sch:createTestDateRequest>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

What could solve this? I just need to add the sch: before the name tag.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using string interpolation:

```
    $soap_client_testmgr.call(:create_test_date, message: {
        :"sch:testMethod" => 'DD',
        :"sch:testPeriodNumber" => $test_period,
        :"sch:testDateTime" => (Date.today+7).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' 00:00:00',
        :"sch:name" => 'Automated test'})
```